# Move features from one layer to another existing layer

Tags: arcpy, error-000258

How can I move Selected features from one layer to another existing layer?
I have tried Copy (Data Management), Copy Features (Data Management), But I got the error:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000258: Output (Layer name) already exists

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the exact syntax you used which resulted in the error?

Comment: have you tried using cursors? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001q000000

Comment: Why not try [Append](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000050000000)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy and Copy Features creates new output.  Have a look at [Append](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000050000000).  It modifies data in place.  You also have the option to start an edit session, and simply copy and paste the features from fc to fc.